# How does ' %f ' work in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

Hey i need to know how %f works , that is how

```
printf("%f",number);
```

extract a floating point number from a series of bits in number.
Consider the code:

```
 main()
{
int i=1;
printf("\nd  %d\nf %f",i,i);
}
```

Output is :

d  1

f -0.000000

So ultimately it doesn't depend on variable 'i', but just depends on the usage of %d and %f(or whatever) i just need to know how %f extracts the float number corresponding to series of bits in 'i'

To all those who misunderstood my question i know that %f can't be used to an integer and would load garbage values if size of integer was smaller than float. As for my case the size of integer and float are 4 bytes.

Let me be clear if value of is 1 then the corresponding binary value of i will be this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 [32 bits]
```

How would %f extract -0.0000 as in this case from this series of bits.(How it knows where to put decimal point etc , i can't find it from IEEE 754)

[PLEASE DO CORRECT ME IF I AM WRONG IN MY EXPLANATION OR ASSUMPION]

Comment: Using the wrong type of variable as an argument to `printf` is undefined behaviour. You shouldn't do it. It'll work in different ways on different platforms, possibly crashing or corrupting data.

Comment: But size of integer and float are both 32s bits in my compiler

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's still undefined behaviour, and could lead to anything.

Comment: %f is double, not float. Variable argument functions always follow default type promotion rule, so floats are always promoted to double

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Thanks for the information. Can you please explain the significance of promotion rule here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined behavior to use `"%f"` to an `int`, so the answer to your question is: you don't need to know, and you shouldn't do it.

The output depends on the format specifier like `"%f"` instead of the type of the argument `i` is because variadic functions (like `printf()` or `scanf()`) have no way of knowing the type of variable argument part.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, giving mismatched "%" specifier and arguments is undefined behavior, and, according to the C standard, anything can happen.

What *does* happen, in this case, on most modern computers, is this:

printf looks at the place in memory where the data should have been, interprets whatever data it finds there as a floating-point number, and prints that number.
Since printf is a function that can take a variable number of arguments, all floats are converted to doubles before being sent to the function, so printf expects to find a double, which (on normal modern computers) is 64 bits. But you send an int, which is only 32 bits, so printf will look at the 32 bits from the int, and 32 more bits of garbage that just happened to be there. When you tried this, it seems that the combination was a bit pattern corresponding to the double floating-point value -0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Well.

It's easy to see how an integer can be packed into bytes, but how do you represent decimals?

The simplest technique is `fixed point`: of the `n` bits, the first `m` are before the point and the rest after. This is not a very good representation, however. Bits are wasted on some numbers, and it has *uniform precision*, while in real life, most desired decimals are between `0` and `1`.

Enter [`floating point`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). The [`IEEE 754`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) spec defines a way of interpreting bits that has, since then, been almost universally accepted. It has very high near-zero precision, is compact, expandable and allows for very large numbers as well.

The linked articles are a good read.

Comment: I think you understood my question in the right way.
I can't find my questions answer in IEEE 754.

The value of i used was 1, so in binary number system it corresponds to
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 [assuming i am correct and size of integer is 32 bits], so how did %f extract -0.0000 from this ? [if size of float is 32 bits]

Answer (score 0):

You can output a floating-point number (`float x;`) manually by treating the value as a "black box" and extracting the digits one-by-one.

First, check if `x < 0`. If so, output a minus-sign `-` and negate the number. Now we know that it is positive.

Next, output the integer portion. Assign the floating-point number to an integer variable, which will truncate it, ie. `int integer = x;`. Then determine how many digits there are using the base-10 logarithm `log10()`. Note, `log10(0)` is undefined, so you'll have to handle zero as a special case. Then iterate from 0 up to the number of digits, each time dividing by 10^digit_index to move the desired digit into the unit's position, and take the 10-residue (modulus).

```
for (i=digits; i>=0; i--)
    dig = (integer / pow(10,i)) % 10;
```

Then, output the decimal point `.`.

For the fractional part, subtract the integer from the original (absolute-value, remember) floating-point number. And output each digit in a similar way, but this time multiplying by 10^frac_digits. You won't be able to predict the number of significant fractional digits this way, so just use a fixed precision (constant number of fractional digits).

I have C code to fill a string with the representation of a floating-point number [here](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/bin/xpost_op_type.c#351), although I make no claims as to its readability.

IEEE formats store the number as a normalized binary fraction. It's more similar to scientific notation, like 3.57×10<sup>2</sup> instead of 357.0. So it is stored as an exponent-mantissa pair. Being "normalized" means there's actually an implicit additional 1 bit at the front of the mantissa that is not stored. Hopefully that's enough to help you understand a more detailed description of the format from elsewhere.

Remember, we're in *binary*, so there's no "decimal point". And with the exponent-mantissa notation, there isn't even a *binary point* in the format. It's implicitly represented in the exponent.

---

On the tangentially-related issue of passing floats to `printf`, remember that this is a *variadic* function. So it does not declare types of arguments that it receives, and all arguments passed undergo automatic conversions. So, `float` will automatically promote to `double`. So what you're doing is (substituting hex for brevity), passing 2 64-bit values:

```
double f,             double f
0xabcdefgh 0xijklmnop 0xabcdefgh 0xijklmnop
```

Then you tell `printf` to interpret this sequence of words as an `int` followed by a `double`. So the 32-bit `int` seen by `printf` is only the first half of the floating-point number, and then the floating-point number seem by `printf` has its words reversed. The fourth word is never used.

To get the integer representation, you'll need to use *type-punning* with a pointer.

```
printf("%d %f\n", *(int *)&f, f);
```

Which reads (from right-to-left): take the address of the float, treat it as a pointer-to-int, follow the pointer.

Comment: “This technique will work in any language with any floating-point format” Some people have found that it did not work on their platform for printing “123”: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/06/Non-experts-need-accurate-floating-point-the-most

Comment: @PascalCuoq Understood. Retracted.